# Player Rigidbody2D not adding force(unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

```
public void Continue9()
{
    player.dialouge1 = false;
    dialogue = true;
    index += 1;
    switch (index)
    {
        case 21:
            conversation3.SetActive(true);
            text3.text = "No... Not farewell";
            image3.sprite = mirage;
            break;
        case 22:
            text3.text = "Whatcha gonna do now...";
            image3.sprite = scourge;
            break;
        case 23:
            text3.text = "TRANSFORM!!!";
            image3.sprite = mirage;
            break;
        case 24:
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.left * speed1, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            conversation3.SetActive(false);
            player.Transforming();
            break;
    }
}
```

In this continue9 function in the last case 24, when I am using the players rigidbody(that has been assigned and is 2D) it doesn't add any sort of force to the player.

Comment: How are you sure?   What is the value of speed1? What if you set it to 500? Are you sure that code is is run?

Answer (score 1):

There can be so many possibilities.

1. The Rigidbody is Kinematic.
2. The function is never called.
3. The force value is not enough.
4. Movement Constraints are applied on the Rigidbody.
5. rb is null

You will have to debug it one by one. This guide to [Unity Rigidbody](https://vionixstudio.com/2023/01/10/unity-rigidbody/) may be helpful.